# Exclude node title in bulk

Tags: nodes

Is there a way to exclude titles in bulk? I want to exclude title of several nodes all at once.

I'm using [Exclude Node Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) to remove node titles to the display. However, I can only edit it one by one by opening and editing each nodes.

What I want is to update nodes by bulk if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by excluding them? Would you explain little more. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I'm using Exclude Node Title to remove node titles to the display. However, I can only edit it one by one by opening and editing each nodes.

What I want is to update nodes by bulk if possible.

Answer (score 0):

override the node template and remove title from there.

Comment: I'm sorry sir. I don't want to remove the title completely. I just want to remove the title to some selected nodes. I'm using Exclude node title module to do this. But, it's done one by one to each nodes. What I want is to do this by mass or by bulk. Just what view bulk operations module does..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What @Mohammad AlQanneh means is the following:

a. Go to your theme / subtheme directory

b. create a file named node--MACHINE-NAME-OF-CONTENT-TYPE.tpl.php (example node--article.tpl.php) and paste the contents of the original node.tpl.php inside it

c. edit the file and remove the HTML / PHP code that prints the title, for example, remove or comment out this:

```
<a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
```

d. clear the caches, that is all.

Comment: No sir. I don't mean to remove all node titles to all nodes. "Exclude node title" module allows title to be removed to the user selected nodes.

But as what I've observed. I can just do it one by one to each page. What I want is a way to select multiple nodes and execute  what "exclude node title" does. 

This may seem to be a VBO (view bulk operation) related functionality, if you're familiar.

Btw, I appreciate it. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->nid == 'your node id' && $vars['node']->type == 'your-content-type') {
    unset($vars['node']->title);
  } 
}
```

Add this code in your template.php and clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand well what you need and here is the way to do it:

a. create a custom Integer field called *field_show_title* with two possible values 1 or 0

b. use VBO to bulk update the desired nodes to set the custom field's value to 1 or 0

c. in the node--???.tpl.php file use PHP's if or switch & case statements to determine if the title should be shown or not based on the value of *field_show_title*

Comment: Thanks for the input sir.. But, for now, I want to know if exclude node title module has this functionality, because if there's not, I will resort to what you've said. Thanks!